# How to make a Twitter Crawler using Scrapy?

Tags: twitter, scrapy, web-crawler

I have tried using Scrapy to scrape data from websites like Pinterest that do not require logged in sessions for data scraping, but how to use Scrapy for scraping and crawling Twitter, since for accessing Twitter followers and other data we need to first log in.

Comment: Why don't use a twitter API instead?

Comment: Don't you read the official documentation first? There is a FAQ there that answers your questions. Because your question is quite a frequently asked one. http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#using-formrequest-from-response-to-simulate-a-user-login

Comment: How about using `selenium`&`scrapy` together

Comment: @alecxe Twitter APIs can not get us tweets than are older than a week.

Answer (score 3):

Login Twitter and get the follower page of someone
An example using Python library Requests:

```
import requests

url = "https://twitter.com/login"
payload = { 'session[username_or_email]': account, 
            'session[password]': password}
r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
```

It would be better to add headers of a browser to request query so that Twitter server would regard the spider as a browser user.

```
# You need to fill the area below after checking the header in your browser
header = {
        'Host': 'twitter.com',
        'User-Agent': ,
        'Accept': ,
        'Accept-Language': ,
        'Accept-Encoding': ,
        'X-Requested-With': ,
        "Cookie": ",
        'Connection': }
url = 'http://twitter.com/%s/followers'%(someone)
p = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Then you get the page and you can parse the page by other stuff like BS4, scrape or anything.

Comment: Twitter is by default public. Robots can crawl pages. Without login you can see individual tweet and list of tweets by handler

Answer (score 2):

I have seen two Scrapy libraries for Twitter so far:

- [scrapy-twitter](https://github.com/yall/scrapy-twitter) - uses Twitter API and gets more data from every tweet
- [TweetScraper](https://github.com/jonbakerfish/TweetScraper) - without Twitter API, but it has powerful query language

Comment: Could you please explain how to use at least 1 of them to solve the question

Comment: This is close to border-line spam. You should edit your question asd @MZaragoza already suggested.

Comment: I think this is closer to a link only answer. But it could be saved with a explanation on how to use ether of the links

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18350394)

Comment: @gre_gor, to be honest, I haven't read the question carefully. I don't know how to scrape followers. I just posted this links since mentioned libraries helps with scraping Twitter.